# SQLite database connection problem Java

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I am trying to do some querys to a database I created but I am having problems connecting to it:

```
enter code here import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class GestorBase{
private  ResultSet resultset;
private static  Connection con;
private  Statement sentencia;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");




    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db/Freepark.sqlite");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("error al buscar la base de datos");
    }

        Statement sentencia = con.createStatement();




    String query = "SELECT * FROM Restaurantes";

    ResultSet resultset = sentencia.executeQuery(query);





        while(resultset.next())
        {
            String nombre = resultset.getString("NOMBRE");
            String calle = resultset.getString("CALLE");
            int codigo = resultset.getInt("CODIGO");
            System.out.println("Codigo de restaurante:   "+codigo+"Nombre de restaurante: "+ nombre +"
        Calle del restaurante: "+ calle);
        }



    }
}
```

And the console message that I get is:

```
error al buscar la base de datos
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GestorBase.main(GestorBase.java:27)
```

The line 27 is the " Statement sentencia = con.createStatement(); " one, so I suppose that thats the nullpointer exception generator? but I also get the "error al buscar en la base de datos" message,witch is the one inside the catch block and that means that there is a problem with the " Statement sentencia = con.createStatement(); " line too right? anyone?:_

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the `con=DriverManager.getConnection` line, masked by the `System.out.println("error al buscar la base de datos");` instruction. The other error is cause by the first one, just ignore it.
To see what the real error is, just remove the `try ... catch` around the `getConnection` call, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db/Freepark.sqlite");
    Statement sentencia = con.createStatement();

    ....

}
```

Comment: I have removed try catch block and now I get this in the console:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: out of memory
 at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
 at org.sqlite.NestedDB._open(NestedDB.java:73)
 at org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:77)
 at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:88)
 at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at GestorBase.main(GestorBase.java:21)
Any idea?:_

Comment: You have an "out of memory" there. Try starting Java with the -Xmx option, for example `-Xmx512m`.